# What would be Firewalld equivalent of this command?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewalld

I installed `IBSng` on my server (Centos 7) and the install guide has been written in according to `iptables`. so I need equivalent of this command in `firewalld` please.

Thanks a bunch

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1300:8000 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1300
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not `--tcp-flags SYN,RST,SYN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a so-called **direct rule** in `firewalld` and keep using the `iptables` syntax:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule filter FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST,SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1300:8000 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1300
```